# Dynamic API is not calling on a scroll in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to take a screenshot of a page in which images are dynamically loading on scroll. Using puppeteer on a scroll, image API is not calling. So all images are not loading for a page. I am using below code. Please help for this.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    
    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/new-arrivals/?link-usage=Header%3A%20New&mc=NewArrivals&lu=Main/', { waitUntil: 'load' });
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1200,
            height: 800
        });
    
        await autoScroll(page);
    
        await page.screenshot({
            path: 'yoursite.png',
            fullPage: true
        });
    
        await browser.close();
    })();
    
    async function autoScroll(page) {
        await page.evaluate(async () => {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var totalHeight = 0;
                var distance = 100;
                var timer = setInterval(() => {
                    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                    window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                    totalHeight += distance;
    
                    if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }, 100);
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to set the page goto to networkidle0 or at least networkidle2, as all of the images in the first "above the fold" need to be loaded.

```
const url = 'https://www.chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/new-arrivals/?link-usage=Header%3A%20New&mc=NewArrivals&lu=Main/'
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
```

Add some close popup
(need to be inside try-catch clause, since this will be likely random or occational)

```
try {
    await page.click('section#browseCart-genericPopup-wrapper button[aria-label="Close Popup"]')
} catch (error) {}
```

This method below need to be evaluated inside the DOM
Check product images by list all of them inside an array

```
const productImages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[aria-label="Product image"] > img'))
```

Since this site works by lazy loading the product images, you need to wait all of images `src` attribute to not contain `data`, and same value as `data-original` attribute value, and all images has complete loading.

```
let completeLoading = image.complete
let imageNotLoading = image.getAttribute('src').startsWith('data')
let imageIsOriginal = image.getAttribute('src') === image.getAttribute('data-original')
```

To test the script you can use this predefined network emulation like below

```
const networkEmulation = {
    slow3G: puppeteer.networkConditions['Slow 3G'],
    fast3G: puppeteer.networkConditions['Fast 3G'],
    dialUp: { download: 15000, upload: 15000, latency: 1000 }
}
    // You can test this load and wait script by uncomment this line below
    // change to relevant and preferred speed like slow3G or fast3G
await page.emulateNetworkConditions(networkEmulation.dialUp)
```

This is the full complete script.
Don't forget to select this solution as the right answer if you find this was helpful and correct.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const url = 'https://www.chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/new-arrivals/?link-usage=Header%3A%20New&mc=NewArrivals&lu=Main/'


;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    })

    const page = await browser.newPage()

//  const networkEmulation = {
//      slow3G: puppeteer.networkConditions['Slow 3G'],
//      fast3G: puppeteer.networkConditions['Fast 3G'],
//      dialUp: { download: 15000, upload: 15000, latency: 1000 }
//  }
    // You can test this load and wait script by uncomment this line below
    // change to relevant and preferred speed like slow3G or fast3G
//  await page.emulateNetworkConditions(networkEmulation.dialUp)

    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800
    })

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 })

    try {
        await page.click('section#browseCart-genericPopup-wrapper button[aria-label="Close Popup"]')
    } catch (error) {}

    await autoScroll(page)

    while (await page.evaluate(() => {
        const productImages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[aria-label="Product image"] > img'))
        return productImages.filter(image => {
            let completeLoading = image.complete
            let imageNotLoading = image.getAttribute('src').startsWith('data')
            let imageIsOriginal = image.getAttribute('src') === image.getAttribute('data-original')
            return !completeLoading || !imageIsOriginal || imageNotLoading
        }).length !== 0
    })) {
        await page.waitForTimeout(500)
    }

    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'yoursite.png',
        fullPage: true
    })

    await browser.close()
})()

async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0
            var distance = 100
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight
                window.scrollBy(0, distance)
                totalHeight += distance
                if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
                    clearInterval(timer)
                    resolve()
                }
            }, 100)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it's not working my side.

Comment: Why is it not working @MurtuzaSanjeliwala ?

Comment: Which version of puppeteer are you using? I am using an old version 5.5.0

emulateNetworkConditions is not working and code inside while loop is not working.

Comment: I've commented the new version functions. Now it will work with any versions.

Comment: It's working perfect now. Thank you very much. Really appreciated.

Comment: Nice if that can help. My pleasure.